# xpages how to set title to be displayed in browser window

Tags: xpages, xpinc

Is there any chance to set a title (for a XPiNC application) to be displayed in the browser window - title?

Currently, the title is changing while the users navigate from one xpage to another xpage. Is it possible to put a constant title?

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a title to your XPage at Properties tab "XPage". You can add a string there or calculate a title.

[image]

The title is visible in XPiNC and browser.

If you want to set the same title to all XPages then define it in a theme: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11802089/2065611.

Comment: Thanks, @Knut. Btw, is there any chance to add a title globally no matter what XPage users are selecting ?

Comment: Yes, you can define a session scope variable and refer to it with `pageTitle="#{sessionScope.PageTitle}"` or you can use a managed bean with a methode getPageTitle() and use it with `pageTitle="#{yourBean.PageTitle}"`

Comment: And the field which use the scoped variable can be declared anywhere , on any xpage/custom control? I can not add some default value for my field which use the scoped variable... arhhh

Comment: Yes. Or, you define a title for all XPages in a theme. I added a link to my answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can set the page title globally using a theme. Just add the following your theme (which will then only set the page title if not individually set):

```
<control override="false">
    <name>ViewRoot</name>
    <property override="false">
        <name>pageTitle</name>
        <value>My title</value>
    </property>
</control>
```

Read [more about themes at xpageswiki.com](http://xpageswiki.com/apps/wiki-xpages/wiki-xpages.nsf/dx/Work_with_themes).

Comment: HTTP Web Server: IBM Notes Exception - File does not exist

Comment: the link is dead